# Insert panel Button widget into HTML table

Tags: python, panel, holoviz

Is it possible to insert - for example - a `pn.widgets.Button()` widget into a HTML table cell in a `pn.pane.HTML()` panel?

Something like:

```
import panel as pn

def button_callback(event):
    pn.pane.Alert("Button clicked!", alert_type="success").show()

button = pn.widgets.Button(name='Click me!')

button.on_click(button_callback)

table_html = f"""
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>{button}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

html_pane = pn.pane.HTML(table_html)

html_pane.show()
```

Unfortunately, in the example above, the button is not represented correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can use GridBox and iterate through the table and add the button at the desired place.

Thanks!